# How do I complete the incomplete symbol on the door in Faron Woods?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

In *Skyward Sword*, after getting the Water Dragon Scales and talking to a Kikwi called Yerbal in the top of the great tree, I need to complete a incomplete symbol to open a door to the last unexplored area.

I've found the completed symbol, yet when I do a skyward strike on the incomplete symbol, nothing happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To draw on it, you need to Fi to acknowledge that you have found the symbol template. Then go to the incomplete symbol and hold your sword up and **do not do a strike!** Instead you must let it charge, and go up to the symbol, then after a second or two you can draw to finish the symbol. It is similar to the process that you use for the Goddess Walls.

Comment: Except you haven't been introduced to Goddess Walls yet at that point.

Comment: Oh yeah… :| But it is the same process. ;)